# create a JavaScript regular expression to correctly parse an HTML script tag and its attributes

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regexp that allows me to parse an HTML script tag. I need the attributes of the tag and also the body

This reg exp works OK when there IS NOT a `>` inside the script tag, like this:

```
let regExp = new RegExp('(<script([\\S\\s]*?)>)([\\S\\s]*?)<\\/script>')
let match = regExp.exec(`<script on:load={onload}>body</script>`)
=>
Array(4) [ 
  "<script on:load={onload}>body</script>", 
  "<script on:load={onload}>", 
  " on:load={onload}", 
  "body" 
]
```

​But if I try with a script that contains a `>` it incorrectly closes the tag, like this:

```
match = regExp.exec(`<script on:load={() => console.log('Hi')}>body</script>`)
Array(4) [ 
  "<script on:load={() => console.log('Hi')}>body</script>", 
  "<script on:load={() =>", // here it is incorrectly closing the script tag on first appearance of a >
  " on:load={() =", 
  " console.log('Hi')}>body" 
]
```

I know I could find other examples that break this regexp, but at least how could I prevent the first group to be closed if it finds a `=>` symbol?

Comment: Where is this purposed to be run?

Comment: Why would you use a regex for this in the first place? You can get the script tag as an element then use the built-in functions to get its attributes and body (e.g. `element.attributes`, `element.innerHTML`)

Comment: remaining in the regex realm you could use negative lookbehind to match a `>` not preceeded by `=` with this `(?<!=)>)`. But as you also pointed out, there are cases that could break that approach anyway. Unfortunately the canonic parser is not applicable because that is not valid html (`on:load`)

Comment: this is an example using the lookbehind https://regex101.com/r/CM9plC/1

Comment: It's [its](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/its#Pronoun), not [it's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it's#Contraction).

Comment: *"I need a regexp that allows me to parse an HTML script tag"*: [it never stops...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)